# How to visualize data from an unstructered mesh in R?

Tags: r, visualization, grid-layout

I've got ASCII data from an numeric ocean model that applies unstructered grids of the form

```
id   lat   lon   value
```

Maybe s.th. like

```
dsize <- 100
data=data.frame(id=seq(1:dsize), 
            lat=sort(runif(dsize)*10+2570740),
            lon=runif(dsize)*10+6926070,
            val=sin(2*pi*(1:dsize)/dsize) + runif(1,-1,1)*10)
```

I want now to visualize that results with (x=lat, y=lon, z=val)

1. 3D, e.g. the rgl library
2. 2D, contour plot
3. sections along lat or lon

I stuck since I do not achieve increasing values for x and y...

Comment: search SO for answers involving `akima`

Answer (score 2):

I think it will help if you interpolate the val variables with e.g. the interp() function from package akima. Is that what you are after?

[image]

```
require(rgl)
require(akima)

dsize <- 100
data=data.frame(id=seq(1:dsize), 
            lat=sort(runif(dsize)*10+2570740),
            lon=runif(dsize)*10+6926070,
            val=sin(2*pi*(1:dsize/dsize + runif(1,-1,1)*10)))

#use akima to interpolate a *val* surface
surf<-interp(data$lat,data$lon,data$val)

persp3d(x=surf$x, y=surf$y, z=surf$z,
    theta=-50, phi=-25, expand=0.75, 
    alpha=0.3, col="green", ticktype="detailed", 
    xlab="lat", ylab="long", zlab="level",axes=TRUE)

rgl.viewpoint( scale=c(1,1,2) )
```